# normal group $(\text{ker }g)(\text{ker } f)$ as a kernel of some group using $f$ and $g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For group homomorphism $f: A\to B$ and $g: A\to C$ we know $\text{ker }f\cap \text{ker } g$ is kernel of $(f,g): A\to B\times C$.

$(\text{ker }g)(\text{ker } f)$ is trivially normal in $A$, can we express it as a kernel of some construction of $B$ and $C$?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are not surjective, I think probably not. The informal answer is "yes, $f\circ g$, the composition of $f$ and $g$." That has some obvious problems, and I don't think they can be fixed if $B$ and $C$ are large, unrelated simple groups.

Comment: @JackSchmidt If you have $A$ $\underline{\text{and }f}$ it doesn't matter how large is $A$, you always have $f(A)$.

Comment: If one cannot assume quotients, then one should not assume images. It is not very hard to give examples of homomorphisms for which we don't know the image in any meaningful way, but we do know the codomain. From logic/combinatorial group theory: take $f$ to be a specific (slightly well chosen) homomorphism from a free group into a general linear group over the rationals of large enough rank and dimension, then given a matrix b in B, there is no algorithm to decide if b in f(B). From computational group theory, same but the field can be finite, and then we will all die before we know.